# Multiple select options are not taking the full width of the box on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styling

I have a multiple select input with a min-width set on the select element.  The options are not taking up the full width of the available select box in Internet Explorer 9.

The items take up the full width on Chrome and Firefox.  How do I make the option elements take the full width of the select input?

Notice the `Saab` item here in Internet Explorer:

[image: Example]

[This Fiddle demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/jacerhea/Ag5Qe/)

```
<select style="min-width: 150px; width: auto;" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" style="width: 100%;">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It works correctly in Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting the css width attribute to 100% for both the select and option, and then the select items filled up the full width:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacerhea/yMXdb/2/)

```
<body>
<form action="form_action.asp">
<select style="min-width: 150px; width: 100%;" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" style="width: 100%;">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, you can't give OPTION a block layout in IE. It will expand only to the width of its content, I don't believe you can fiddle with its width. You can, as you've demonstrated, adjust the width of the SELECT element without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it out in some odd way it dont understand your auto width on the select - but if you just set it to a pixel size you will get a full width marker on it:

[See it here FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag5Qe/6/)

The code:

```
<form action="form_action.asp">
<select style="min-width: 150px; width: 1px;" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" style="width: 100%;">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I didn't mention that I wanted the select tag to expand and contract with the size of the container. That's why the width was auto.  With this, the width will always be 150px.

Comment: @JaceRhea yeah i would do a hole other approach if you going to style a select with its options - its really bad supported in older browser - i would go for a javascript solution their are a lot of people out there allready done it and shared like this: http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/ or this http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/ or build it my self like a jquery plugin build on ul and li's